# Proving a set is bounded using convergence

Tags: real-analysis

If $x_n$ is a sequence converging to a limit $L$, show that $X= \lbrace x_n : n\in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ is bounded.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $x_n$ converges to $L$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \implies |x_n - L| < \epsilon$. Set $M =  \max (|x_0|, |x_1|, ... , |x_n|, |L| + \epsilon).$
Thus, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, |x_n| \leq M.$ So, $-M \leq x_n \leq M.$ Thus $X$ bounded above by $M$ and below by $-M$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You should pick an epsilon, for example $\epsilon  =17$. The max should be $\max (|x_0|,|x_1|,...,|x_N|,|L|+17)$. (notice the capital N, you don't need $|L|-\epsilon$ since it is redundant)

Comment: To prove a set is bounded, are we allowed to choose any epsilon? I assumed that we had to keep it arbitrary and positive to allow the proof to be generalized.

Answer (score 1):

Idea is certainly correct. The execution a little less. First, you never specified what $\epsilon$ is. Second, you should use absolute values sign in the definition of $M$ around the $x_0,x_1, \dots, x_n$. Because, what happens when these are negative?

Here is how I would write it down.

Fix your favorite $\epsilon > 0$, for example we use $\epsilon=1$. Choose $n_0$ such that $|x_n-L| < 1$ for $n \geq n_0$. Then, we have $|x_n| \leq |L|+1 $ for $n\geq n_0$. Putting $M:=\max\{|x_0|, \dots, |x_{n_0-1}|, |L|+1\}$, we see that $|x_n| \leq M$ for $n \geq 0$. Hence, $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is bounded

Comment: Just changed some things, is it correct now?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. But you really should say that we fix an $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: To prove a set is bounded, are we allowed to choose any epsilon? I assumed that we had to keep it arbitrary and positive to allow the proof to be generalized

Comment: Moreover, don't change your attempt but rather add a new attempt because otherwise my answer is nonsense. It refers to content in your post which isn't there anymore.

Comment: A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is bounded if there exists $M > 0$ such that $|x| \leq M$ for all $x \in A$. So, finding one upper bound suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $(-2,-1,1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots)$ converging to $0$. Set $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}.$ Then $M=1$ and not all elements fulfil the inequality $-M\le x_n\le M$.

Comment: $M=1$ in this example?

Comment: Yes, of course. Corrected. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The proof is consistent. To make it more elegant, you could take $\epsilon = 1$. About literary style, I like to avoid too many symbols. But this is personal.